# Changing the file in tmp directory does not pick up the changes automatically in JBoss 5

Tags: deployment, jboss5.x

I used to change jsp, xml, xsl files in the tmp directory and Jboss 4 used to pick up these changes automatically w/o any build and restart. Refreshing the required page was giving me the changes reflected. However this doesn't seem to work in Jboss 5.1.0. Can anybody help me achieving this in jboss 5.1.0?

Answer (score 1):

Your JSP might have an error in it. Edit it in Eclipse first, Eclipse will tell you if there is an error, then copy it across to the tmp directory. If it has an error in it it will not be compiled and JBOSS will use the previous version.

Hope this works, it worked for me, I was getting the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Would you please check if [Hot Deploy](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/jboss51disableenablehotdeployhdscanner) is enabled?

Comment: Hi,
  Thanks for your reply. I tried your suggestion but using twiddle for redeploy gives me exception as follow.

DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR:
  Deployment "vfszip:/c:/jboss/server/jb5/deploy/adsuite.ear/" is in error due t
o the following reason(s): java.lang.IllegalStateException: domain-hibernate:app
=AdSuite is already installed.

        This might be due to the way I build my project through ant.
do you have any idea about it?

Thanks
Vijay